# How to read nested loop json values from appsettings.json and assign to object

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

```
"SalesOrderFilters": {
    "skip": 0,
    "take": 0,
    "sort": [
      {
        "sortBy": "productGroup",
        "sortDirection": "Ascending"
      }
    ],
    "filters": [
      {
        "columnFilters": [
          {
            "field": "productGroup",
            "operator": "eq",
            "value": "CC05"
          },
          {
            "field": "productGroup",
            "operator": "eq",
            "value": "CC07"
          }
        ],
        "logic": "or"
      },
      {
        "columnFilters": [
          {
            "field": "specFileDate",
            "operator": "lte",
            "value": "6/26/2017 11:17:20 AM"
          },
          {
            "field": "specFileDate",
            "operator": "gte",
            "value": "4/26/2017 11:17:20 AM"
          }
        ],
        "logic": "and"
      },
      {
        "columnFilters": [
          {
            "field": "designSpecialIndicator",
            "operator": "eq",
            "value": "N"
          }
        ],
        "logic": "and"
      },
      {
        "columnFilters": [
          {
            "field": "buMfgLocId",
            "operator": "eq",
            "value": "5"
          }
        ],
        "logic": "and"
      },
      {
        "columnFilters": [
          {
            "field": "orderType",
            "operator": "eq",
            "value": "SO"
          }
        ],
        "logic": "and"
      },
      {
        "columnFilters": [
          {
            "field": "buMfgLocation",
            "operator": "contains",
            "value": "lexi"
          }
        ],
        "logic": "and"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: I imagine this question may need altering to avoid closure, adding some context of what you're trying to do and what isn't working so far.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the [options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

> The options pattern uses classes to provide strongly typed access to groups of related settings. When configuration settings are isolated by scenario into separate classes, the app adheres to two important software engineering principles:
>
> The Interface Segregation Principle (ISP) or Encapsulation: Scenarios
> (classes) that depend on configuration settings depend only on the
> configuration settings that they use. Separation of Concerns: Settings
> for different parts of the app aren't dependent or coupled to one
> another.

Answer (score 0):

Just want to share how I do it on my apps (assuming appsettings.json is your default config file):

```
public class ConfigHelper : IConfigHelper
{
    private IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public ConfigHelper(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public string GetAppSettings(string key)
    {
        return Configuration[key];
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
...
ConfigHelper.GetAppSettings("SalesOrderFilters:Skip");
...
```

Or this approach:

create a class to represent your config:

```
public class SalesOrderFilters
{
    public int Skip { get; set; }
    public int Take { get; set; }
    public List<Filters> Filters { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class Filter
{
   public List<ColumnFilter> ColumnFilters { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

in your Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ...
    services.AddSingleton(typeof(SalesOrderFilters), Configuration.GetSection("SalesOrderFilters").Get<SalesOrderFilters>());
    ...
}
```

And then you can inject this object in your controllers/service classes:

```
public class MyController
{
    private SalesOrderFilters _settings;

    public MyController(SalesOrderFilters settings)
    {
        _settings = settings;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but how to read inside the "columnFilters" values from json ?

Comment: You can try the approach here https://www.thetopsites.net/article/52769655.shtml or another possible approach (which is what I mostly do) is the edit on my answer :)